# Simple attempt at NSTableView and it's not showing anything

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I'm trying to use NSTableView (it's my first attempt at it) but it's showing nothing.
I created a project (ARC), i have a tableview in my xib, i dragged the "Data Source" and "Delegate" to my AppDelegate Object.
I have the following code on AppDelegate.h :

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource>{
    NSMutableArray* array;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTableView *tableView;

@end
```

And .m :

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize tableView = _tableView;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [array addObject:@"1"];
    [array addObject:@"2"];
    [array addObject:@"3"];
    [array addObject:@"4"];
    [_tableView reloadData];
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *) aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *) aTableColumn row:(NSInteger) rowIndex{  
    return [array objectAtIndex:rowIndex];  
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView{
    return [array count];  
}

@end
```

What could be the error? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the code you've posted is complete, the problem seems to be that you never initialize the `array` instance variable. Add the following line to the top of `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:`:

```
array = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Comment: i did that and it's still not showing anything inside the tableview

Comment: It's impossible for people on Stack Overflow to thoroughly debug your code remotely. The only thing we can do is take the information you provide and try to spot obvious problems and suggest places to look. My suggestion is to use the debugger to step through your code and find where it's not behaving the way you expect. Making sure that `-tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:` is being called, and that `array` is not nil or empty there seems like a good start.

Comment: i just deleted my project, created a new one with the same things and now it's working perfectly. thanks anyway!